# Trying to change all the periods in my file to exclamation points

Tags: c

So I have a file on my computer, file.txt, in which I have written a few sentences and ended them with periods (.)
I want to be able to run my code, and have all the periods change to exclamation points.
I wrote this:

```
int main(){
  FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
  if(fp == NULL)
    return -1;

  char c;
  while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    if(c == '.')
      c = '!';
    fputc(c, fp);


  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

My thought process was to open the file, read it character by character, and if the character is a period, reset it to an exclamation point.

Currently when I run it the file it does not give me any errors but it does not change the file in any way.

Edit: I have all the includes needed

Comment: Is the code in the question a character-for-character replica of the code you're running? If so, you don't have braces in your while loop, so `fputc` will only run once the while loop has finished.

Comment: Your code says the `while` and `if` statements are only supposed to run a single statement since you've not specified any braces to indicate they've multiple syntax to work with.

Comment: Also, please change `char c;` to `int c;` because `fgetc` returns the `int` type. It won't matter so much for a text file, but please get into the habit because you need to be able to distinguish `EOF` from `0xFF`. Very few (any?) C library functions take a `char` parameter or return a `char` value. Note too that `'!'` has type `int`.

Comment: You can't use `fputc()` after `fgetc()` like that. The `fopen` man page says *"When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, **when you switch from reading to writing**, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. When you **switch from writing to reading**, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function."*

Comment: ... anyway think about the process: you read a character, the file pointer moves to the next position, so when you write, where does to the data get written? Not at the place you read from. You must `fseek` back to that position, and then `fflush` the output as mentioned about. Much easier, it to just write to a new file.

Comment: @WeatherVane Didn't really realize it was such a hassle to change it in the same file. I will try to code it so it copies it to a different file.

Comment: Don't forget to `{` brace `}` the code block.

Comment: @WeatherVane So would the logic from my original post work by opening the first file for reading, a second file for writing, and putc(c, the file for writing)? And adding the correct braces..

Comment: Yes, but please change `char c;` to `int c;` The terms 'character' and `char` are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane I ran the same code with these changes: Declared a file pointer to another file, opened it for writing. Changed the char to an int. And changed the putc to: putc(c, fp2); It opened the second file, but doesn't seem to be outputting anything to it.

Comment: Please ask a new question!